Customize text options popup in OneNote to include strikethrough
Is there a setting in Microsoft OneNote or an add-in that allows customizing the text options popup that appears when selecting text?:

Specifically, I would like to be able to access some of the features that are present in the Home menu ribbon but missing in the popup like strikethrough (going through that menu or using keyboard shortcuts isn't as handy for me).
